# Is it correct? I "am trying fixing this"?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Actually, I'd like to know if is correct to say: **"I am trying fixing this"**, or should use the more obvious **"I am trying to fix this"**?

If the first one is correct, is there a name for this kind of syntax/conjugation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the verb *to try* is being used in the sense of *to attempt*, then it is generally followed by *to + infinitive* rather the *-ing form* of the verb. So, assuming that the trying here is attempting, it should be:

- I am trying to fix this.

If, on the other hand, the verb is being used in the sense of *testing something out* (e.g. to see if it works or if you like it), then it is usual to follow it with the gerund:

- I'm trying wearing contact lenses (to see if I like them).
- I'm trying drinking milk before bedtime (to see if I can cure my insomnia).

However, the difference between the two senses of *try* is not always so clear-cut. A popular song from poor Alicia Keys has the lines:

> Have you ever tried sleeping with a broken heart?
> Well you could try sleeping in my bed.

where the first *try* seems to mean *attempt* and the second means *test out*.

[And Irene is right that consecutive *-ing forms* can sound a little awkward.]

Answer (score 6):

Although it is possible to have an *-ing* form after the verb **try**, two consecutive *-ing* forms sound very unnatural, so you'd better avoid it.

Comment: +1 Thanks for letting me know that it sounds unnatural to native speakers =)